# Why aren't I getting any definitions when I type "get-command -type cmdlet"?

Tags: powershell, definition, powershell-cmdlet

This is my first day learning powershell so forgive me if this is a silly question...

But the instruction video I am watching shows the teacher typing in  "get-command -type cmdlet" to demonstrate how to get a list of all available cmdlets and their definitions. I'm getting the cmdlets, but my powershell is not listing the definitions. I'm attaching screenshots to show you the what he has and what I have. what changes do I have to make to get this fixed?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for these answers. They were helpful for this newbie! :)

Answer (score 0):

Cmdlets are written in C#.  They are compiled and you can't normally see the definitions, if you're talking about seeing the source code.

Comment: I'm not disregarding anything. This is an issue that came up within the first 5 minutes of me learning powershell. Up until you mentioned it I've never even heard of "get-help" before.

Comment: @Tommy I am not commenting on your question but on @js2010`s answer.

Answer (score 0):

The definition property may not be appearing becuse PowerShell is formatting it for your display. The definition is likely to be too long for your console display, so it will end with '...'.

Use the following to see all of the member properties available. Based on that, you can choose which properties you want to see.

```
Get-Command -Type Cmdlet | Format-List -Property Name, Definition
```

If you want to see PowerShell code, this might be interesting.

```
Get-Command -Type Function |
    Where-Object { $_.Definition.Length -gt 0 } |
    Select-Object -Property Name,Definition |
    Format-List
```

See all of the propety members available.

```
PS H:\> Get-Command -Type Cmdlet | Get-Member

   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.CmdletInfo

Name                MemberType     Definition
----                ----------     ----------
Equals              Method         bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode         Method         int GetHashCode()
GetType             Method         type GetType()
ResolveParameter    Method         System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata ResolveParameter(string name)
ToString            Method         string ToString()
CommandType         Property       System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes CommandType {get;}
DefaultParameterSet Property       string DefaultParameterSet {get;}
Definition          Property       string Definition {get;}
HelpFile            Property       string HelpFile {get;}
ImplementingType    Property       type ImplementingType {get;}
Module              Property       psmoduleinfo Module {get;}
ModuleName          Property       string ModuleName {get;}
Name                Property       string Name {get;}
Noun                Property       string Noun {get;}
Options             Property       System.Management.Automation.ScopedItemOptions Options {get;set;}
OutputType          Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[System.Management.Automation.PSTypeName] OutputType {get;}
Parameters          Property       System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata] Parameters {get;}
ParameterSets       Property       System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection[System.Management.Automation.CommandParameterSetInfo] ParameterSets...
PSSnapIn            Property       System.Management.Automation.PSSnapInInfo PSSnapIn {get;}
RemotingCapability  Property       System.Management.Automation.RemotingCapability RemotingCapability {get;}
Source              Property       string Source {get;}
Verb                Property       string Verb {get;}
Version             Property       version Version {get;}
Visibility          Property       System.Management.Automation.SessionStateEntryVisibility Visibility {get;set;}
DLL                 ScriptProperty System.Object DLL {get=$this.ImplementingType.Assembly.Location;}
HelpUri             ScriptProperty System.Object HelpUri {get=$oldProgressPreference = $ProgressPreference...
```

Comment: I'm sure it's not a formatting issue. I'm using an ultrawide monitor and there are tons of room left for more things to display. Unless there is a configuration in powershell so that it only displays certain information no matter what. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The command `get-command -type cmdlet` does not show definitions. Perhaps you want to see the definition of `get-command`? :)

To see definitions, you can use one of two things, if the command supports it, you can simply add a `-?` after the command to get help. Example:

```
get-command -?
```

`-?` is equivalent to `--h` or `--help` in bash. Some commands don't support taht since that would be an argument in the command like in `if` commands. For these types of commands, you can use:

```
get-help if
```

And it will either show you help for `if` or show you things that have similar names that you can get help about. An example of this would be the `break` command. `break` does not support the `-?` method so you would have to use `get-help break` but it will not appear there either. Instead you get the output of:

```
Name                              Category  Module                    Synopsis
----                              --------  ------                    --------
Disable-PSBreakpoint              Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.U... Disables the breakpoints in the current console.
Enable-PSBreakpoint               Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.U... Enables the breakpoints in the current console.
Get-PSBreakpoint                  Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.U... Gets the breakpoints that are set in the curre...
Remove-PSBreakpoint               Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.U... Deletes breakpoints from the current console.
Set-PSBreakpoint                  Cmdlet    Microsoft.PowerShell.U... Sets a breakpoint on a line, command, or varia...
about_Break                       HelpFile                            Describes a statement you can use to immediate...
```

Which you can see has the `break` help-file under the alias `about_Break`. So if I type `get-help about_Break` it will show me help.

You can also use get-help to find all `cmdlets` like with `get-command` with `get-help -type cmdlet` but if you want to check that out I suggest you look at help for get-help :).

**MORE INFO** (Literally): You can find more info about certain cmdlets if it is available using one of the four commands below:

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help <command name> -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help <command name> -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help <command name> -full".
For online help, type: "get-help <command name> -online"
```

For example (no pun intended), you can find help on `get-help` using:

```
get-help Get-Help -examples
get-help Get-Help -detailed
get-help Get-Help -full
get-help Get-Help -online
```

and the switches will have the criteria above (examples, extra information, technical information, and online help since there is more documentation for things online)